# Is there a Regex code to combine the codes I have to lookabove and look between a line?

Tags: regex

Lets say this is my teststring:

```
XXX 3.14 QQQ
XXX 3.14 QQQ
YYY
```

I would like to have the second 3.14 as the exact match. I think this would require me to combine the next two code lines:

- `((?<=XXX ).*(?= QQQ))` which selects both 3.14.
- `.*\n(?=((.*\n){1})(YYY))` which selects the full second line.

However, when I use `((?<=XXX ).*(?= QQQ)).*\n(?=((.*\n){1})(YYY))` the exact match is the second "3.14" and "QQQ".

Any help would with finding out how to match the second 3.14 with the use of these formulas would very much be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is really your string and not just a part of it, you could make use of `\A`, *the very beginning of a string*:

```
^(?<!\A)XXX(.+?)QQQ$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/MyR5ZZ/1/).

---

It might be easier to specify your programming language and to use the corresponding array location in the found matches (e.g. `results[1]`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the second number, you could also match the exact content instead of using lookarounds and use a single capturing group for the second value.

```
^XXX \d+\.\d+ QQQ\r?\nXXX (\d+\.\d+) QQQ\r?\nYYY\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `XXX \d+\.\d+ QQQ` match the first line
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `XXX (\d+\.\d+) QQQ` Match the second line and capture the number in a capture group
- `\r?\nYYY\b` Match a newline, YYY and word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r01ltu/1)

Answer (score 0):

You where on the correct path, the following should work:

```
(?<=^XXX )[^\n]*(?= QQQ$)(?!.*^XXX [^\n]* QQQ$)
```

Which says match everything (unless a newline) between `<start of line>XXX`  and  `QQQ<end of line>`, if not followed by another sequence of `^XXX [^\n]* QQQ$`.

For the above regex to function appropriately you'll need to set the multiline flag (`m`) to let `^` and `$` match the beginning and ending of a line, rather than the string. You also need to set the single line/dot all flag (`s`).

If you don't care about the `XXX` being adjacent to the start of the line and `QQQ` being adjacent to the end of the line you can leave out the `^` and `$` anchors and don't have to set the multiline flag. This version would look like:

```
(?<=XXX )[^\n]*?(?= QQQ)(?!.*XXX [^\n]* QQQ)
```